# How to bind individual UrlPrefix to a particular network interface?

Tags: iis, http.sys

I am asking how to bind an UrlPrefix to a particular network interface via HTTP Server API (aka http.sys).
It seems IIS somehow can do this.

[image: iis site binding window]

Netsh shows the interface IP as part of the UrlPrefix

```
> netsh http show servicestate view="requestq"
...
Number of registered URLs: 1
Registered URLs:
    HTTP://TEST.SITE.INVALID:80:192.168.202.142/
...                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And it works - curl returns error when i am trying to access the site via the localhost interface

```
> curl.exe -vi --connect-to "test.site.invalid:80:192.168.202.142:80"  http://test.site.invalid/something.html
... 200 OK

> curl.exe -vi --connect-to "test.site.invalid:80:127.0.0.1:80"  http://test.site.invalid/something.html
... 404 Not Found
```

I couldn't find any mentions about such type of binding in the http server api docs. Moveover it says [completely opposite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/ip-listen-list)

> By default, once a registration is entered in the request queue, the HTTP Server API binds to the port specified in the UrlPrefix (for example port 80) for **all IP addresses** (INADDR_ANY or INADDR6_ANY) available on the machine.

You can add/delete a particular interface ip to the ip listen list on a whole host level but not for the individual urlprefix. Anyway the list is empty on my machine:

```
> netsh http show iplist

IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
-------------------------------------------

... nothing in the list
```

It is puzzling me, does IIS use some undocumented API? Anybody know?

Comment: `test.site.invalid:80:127.0.0.1:80` Is this your localhost ip? Have you bound the host name with ip address in the hosts file? By default, the IP listen list is empt. iis does not use some undocumented api.

Comment: @samwu 127.0.0.1 is everybody loopback address, believe me :) No, i did not change the hosts file - the whole string above is the curl command-line option to override DNS resolution and to use the specified IP for connection.

Comment: @samwu ... So if IIS does not use undocumented API - then do you know how to get such binding using the documented HTTP Server API?